# LINK : fatal error LNK1171: unable to load mspdb140.dll (error code: 127)

Tags: python-3.x, dll, nlp, pip, rasa-nlu

I am trying to install `pip install rasa_core` and already added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin;` in my system path variable.

How can I resolve this error?

Following is my output while installing the rasa_core:

```
-3.5\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
    copying src\twisted\mail\test\rfc822.message -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\twis
ted\mail\test
    copying src\twisted\python\test\_deprecatetests.py.3only -> build\lib.win-am
d64-3.5\twisted\python\test
    copying src\twisted\words\im\instancemessenger.glade -> build\lib.win-amd64-
3.5\twisted\words\im
    copying src\twisted\words\xish\xpathparser.g -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\twis
ted\words\xish
    running build_ext
    building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\twisted
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\twisted\test
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe
/c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -ID:\Anaconda\envs\chatbot_p35\inc
lude -ID:\Anaconda\envs\chatbot_p35\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.
14393.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um"
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared" "-IC:\Pro
gram Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x
86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt" /Tcsrc/twisted/test/raiser.c /Fo
build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj
    raiser.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.ex
e /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPA
TH:D:\Anaconda\envs\chatbot_p35\libs /LIBPATH:D:\Anaconda\envs\chatbot_p35\PCbui
ld\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\am
d64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB
\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.14393.0\ucrt\x
64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/L
IBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.14393.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:P
yInit_raiser build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj /OUT:b
uild\lib.win-amd64-3.5\twisted\test\raiser.cp35-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp
.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src/twisted/test\raiser.cp35-win_amd64.lib
    LINK : fatal error LNK1171: unable to load mspdb140.dll (error code: 127)
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\B
IN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1171
```

Comment: Not exact solution but based on error in the post this link might help check this https://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/3203-vs2015-and-incorrect-mspdb140dll-version

Comment: Did you install [Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable](https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/2/5/72572684-052f-4aa9-9170-9d40813a87be/vc_redist.x64.exe)?

Comment: Yes. I did. I tried to uninstall and install once again it works.